# Laravel Supervisor - SMTP issue stopping the code even email is sending through queue

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, laravel-queue, laravel-events

I have supervisor installed to run the code using Laravel queue in background

I am using this things to send an email usually and using SMTP to send an email

But whenever there is any issue with SMTP connection, my code get stopped and firing 500 error even email sending is done through Laravel queue & Supervisor

How i call an event

```
event(new ClientRequestSubmitEvent($param1, $param2, $param3);
```

How `ClientRequestSubmitEvent.php` looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ClientRequestSubmitEvent implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithSockets;
    use SerializesModels;

    public $userId;
    public $clientId;
    public $requestData;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($userId, $clientId, $requestData)
    {
        $this->userId    = $userId;
        $this->clientId  = $clientId;
        $this->requestData = $requestData;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

How Listener `ClientRequestSubmitListener.php` looks like

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use App\Events\ClientRequestSubmitEvent;
use App\Mail\ClientRequestSubmitMail;
use App\Models\Client;
use App\Models\ClientHasResource;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class ClientRequestSubmitListener implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(ClientRequestSubmitEvent $event)
    {
        
    Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new ClientRequestSubmitMail($event));
    }
}
```

Queue settings in .env is like below

Can anyone help.

Thank You

Comment: what is the queue driver set in your .env? Also are you sure you are sending mail to Queue? Try to add a few codes too on your question, of Mail sent. This will never happen if your queue is working properly.

Comment: @AnujShrestha connection should not be sync right? it should be database right?

Comment: yes it should be other than `sync`

Comment: Undetstood, just post your answer, i will make it accepable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it run on background the Queue connection should be other than `sync`, eg: `database`, 'redis`etc; in`.env` file

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```